# Accessing & Sending Phone Call(of the other party) To The Server

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile-development

I have an app idea for a school project, where I need to send the call recording of the other party to a server. I am running a nodejs server which is ready to receive a Buffer or Blob. So all I need to do is, make an app that will run on every phone call, and as soon as the call is finished, only capture the other party's audio stream, convert it into a Buffer or Blob and send it to the my server.

Is this possible to do in Android? I googled and found that there are certain limiations on being able to record phone calls now, not something I would like to found out as a newbie :)

Please share your thoughts on this. Or if you have an alternative approach of doing this. Thanks in advance <3